# Count 1st instance of keyword in list with no duplicate counts in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, stringr

I have a list of keywords:

```
library(stringr)
words <- as.character(c("decomposed", "no diagnosis","decomposition","autolysed","maggots", "poor body", "poor","not suitable", "not possible"))
```

I want to match these keywords to text in a data frame column (df$text) and count the number of times a keyword occurs in a different data.frame (matchdf):

```
matchdf<- data.frame(Keywords=words)
m_match<-sapply(1:length(words), function(x) sum(str_count(tolower(df$text),words[[x]])))
matchdf$matchs<-m_match
```

However, I've noticed that this method counts EACH occurrence of a keyword within a column. eg)

```
"The sample was too decomposed to perform an analysis. The decomposed sample indicated that this animal was dead for a long time"
```

Would then return a count of 2. However, I only want to count the first instance of "decomposed" within a field.

I thought there would be a way to only count the first instance using `str_count` but there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: Don't you want `str_detect` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stringr isn't strictly necessary in this example, `grepl` from base R will suffice. That said, use `str_detect` instead of `grepl`, if you prefer the package function (as pointed out by @Chi-Pak in comment)

```
library(stringr)

words <- c("decomposed", "no diagnosis","decomposition","autolysed","maggots", 
           "poor body", "poor","not suitable", "not possible")

df <- data.frame( text = "The sample was too decomposed to perform an analysis. The decomposed sample indicated that this animal was dead for a long time")

matchdf <- data.frame(Keywords = words, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Base R grepl
matchdf$matches1 <- sapply(1:length(words), function(x) as.numeric(grepl(words[x], tolower(df$text))))

# Stringr function
matchdf$matches2 <- sapply(1:length(words), function(x) as.numeric(str_detect(tolower(df$text),words[[x]])))

matchdf
```

Result

```
       Keywords matches1 matches2
1    decomposed        1        1
2  no diagnosis        0        0
3 decomposition        0        0
4     autolysed        0        0
5       maggots        0        0
6     poor body        0        0
7          poor        0        0
8  not suitable        0        0
9  not possible        0        0
```